# In which option, the diode will make the lm78xx circuit safer

Tags: diodes, voltage-regulator, short-circuit, 7805, lm78xx

[image]

This image was taken from Fairchild's datasheet on lm78xx. I have already built a working example of it, but I am still thinking about adding some additional diode protection (D1, D2). Which option should I go for? Are any of these necessary, or does the short circuit protection cover all backwards current flow dangers? Will any of these diodes add noise to the circuit? Thank you for help.

Comment: You already effectively have D1 in the form of Q1's collector-base junction.

Comment: "Safer" in what context?

Comment: D2 will introduce a voltage offset at the output.